# Algorithm for recovering paired lists when elements are broken

Tags: algorithms, strings

I am trying to solve an algorithmic problem.  I came from http://math.stackexchange.com upon an advise that this forum would be a better place to ask this.

I would like to hear your advice on where to search for hints.  If my problem has got a name, I would like to know what it is called in the field, and what I should learn to solve it.  Any partial suggestion would be welcome.  Also if there is another forum that fits my question better than here, I would be happy to hear that too.

A description of my problem is as follows.  Suppose you have a number of pairs of objects.  Let $X$ be the first list of objects and $Y$ be the second list. Assume $X = Y$ in a sense they share the same list of objects.

Now, objects in both lists are "broken" into pieces; Each element $x \in X$ is decomposed to $x_1, x_2,...$.  The same happens for $Y$.  As a result, what you have is two sets $X', Y'$, which contain the broken pieces of the original objects.
The task is to recover the original objects in $X$ and $Y$ from $X'$ and $Y'$.

Here is an example where objects are strings.
Suppose $X = Y = [apple, banana]$, and the strings are decomposed as:
$X' = [ban, le, ana, app]$ and $Y' = [na, ple, ap, na, ba]$.  I would like to recover $banana$ and $apple$ from information $X'$ and $Y'$.

Does this problem have a name?  Or, what do you think the good things to learn for me to study this type of problem?

Comment: Looks very similar to [shotgun sequencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_sequencing) to me. Without further restrictions there is not necessarily a unique answer; are you satisfied with *any* answer? Which words are allowed outputs? (Consider the pathologic example of X=Y -- what should be the result?)

Comment: Hi, @Rapahel.  Yes, I recognize that the answer is not unique, and I would prefer an answer with the longest list.  In the (banana, apple) example above,  there are three answers `(banana and apple)` `(bananaapply)` and `(applebanana)`.   Among them, the first one is preferred because it is longer than the others.  If there are two or more answers with the same list lengths, then I would be good with any of them.

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916671/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the literature on algorithms for the [shotgun sequencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_sequencing) and [shortest common supersequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem) problems.  It appears that your problem might not be exactly identical to them, but researchers have developed sophisticated algorithmic techniques for handling this kind of problem.  Therefore, I suspect you might be able to use the same techniques for your problem, or adapt them to work well for your situation.